# How && works exactly in JS?

Tags: javascript

I was learning React came across this code:

```
const areNewValuesSortedAccordingly =
   areThresholdValuesSortedAccordingly(newValues) &&
   areThresholdValuesLessThenMaxValueAndMoreThanMinValue(
      newValues,
      maxValueForThreshold,
      minValueForThreshold
   ) &&
   true;
```

My thinking process is this, firstly, only if **"`areThresholdValuesSortedAccordingly(newValues)`"** returns true then **"`areThresholdValuesLessThenMaxValueAndMoreThanMinValue`"** will be invoked. And only if **"`areThresholdValuesLessThenMaxValueAndMoreThanMinValue`"** returns true then **'true'** will be returned. Is that right? But what if any of those two functions return false, I think undefined will be returned and undefined will turn into false. Is that right?

Comment: i think a chain of && will return the first falsy or last truthy value

Comment: `&&` returns its first _operand_, if it can be evaluated to falsy, otherwise the operator returns its second _operator_ . Notice, that the operands are not necessarily booleans.

Comment: `A && B` returns the value A if A can be coerced into `false` otherwise, it returns B.

Comment: @Teemu, you mean, for example, 0 && true. Will 0 be returned or 0 will be converted to false and false will be returned. WHich is true?

Comment: `0` will be returned, nothing is converted, one of the operands is always returned as it is. You can easily make tests with the console.